# Hide/show title of multiple buttons at a time

Tags: ios, button, hide, title

I have an xib auto layout. I am trying to make a bunch of buttons show/hide their Titles by using one of those slider oval switches.

I put the buttons in an array. then tried to turn on and off the button titles. here's the code so far. Not working. newbie huge thanks!

```
// buttons array 
self.myButtonCollection = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.D1Outlet,self.SlapOutlet,self.G7Outlet,self.A8Outlet,self.Bb3Outlet,self.D1Outlet,self.A2Outlet,self.F6Outlet,self.C4Outlet,self.D5Outlet,nil];

//Here is the switch notes code:

- (IBAction)switchNotes:(id)sender
{
    if([sender isOn])
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is ON"); 
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection)
        {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:0.0f];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Switch is OFF");
        for(UIButton *myButton in self.myButtonCollection)
        {
            [myButton setTitleColor:[BT_color getColorFromHexString:@"#000000"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [myButton setAlpha:1.0f];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that method being called ?

Comment: I hit the Switch and activates that code right? I can see in console the slog for the switch on and off. thanks for any help!